# ag-grid actualComparator error

Tags: date, filter, vuejs2, ag-grid

i'm building an ag-Grid in Vue.js . I'm trying to set colDefs and dataRow dinamically, and all is ok but i've ***"actualComparator is not a function"*** error when i set a date filter.

coldefs are dinamics and i receive from json

```
colDefs:[
{
  "field" : "field1",
  "filter" : "text",
  "headerName" : "Name",
  "width" : 100},
{
  "field" : "filed2",
  "filter" : "text",
  "headerName" : "Surname",
  "width" : 80},
{
  "field" : "date1",
  "filter" : "agDateColumnFilter",
  "filterParams" : {
    "clearButton" : true,
    "comparator" : "dateFilterComparator"
   },
  "headerName" : "Birth",
  "width" : 150
}]
```

dateFieldComparator is a function inside the methods

```
dateFilterComparator(filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue){
  console.log("I'm here");
  var dateAsString = cellValue;
  if (dateAsString == null) return -1;
  var dateParts  = dateAsString.split("/");
  var cellDate = new Date(Number(dateParts[2]), Number(dateParts[1]) - 1, Number(dateParts[0]));

  if (filterLocalDateAtMidnight == cellDate) {
    return 0;
  }
  else if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

The request for the json (dataRow + colDefs) is send on the beforeMount eventhook, ag-grid is showed correctly but when i try to set a filter on the date i receive the error above.

The **Clear Filter** button is showed but the comparator seems not initialized with my function ***dataParamComparator***.

I've try to call the ***gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs()*** on the onReady but without success.

Regards

Davide